# Defining the signed area function given two lines

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am having trouble seeing the underlying logic in this question.

> Define a function $A(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt$ to compute the signed area of $y(t)$:
> [image]

Clearly, I need to define two functions first. One part goes from $(-\infty,2)$ and the other $(2,\infty)$.

- When $x \leq 2$ I will just define $L(x) = 2x$.
- When $x>2$ I will define $R(x) = 6-x$.

Now my problem is when actually defining $A(x)$ itself. My first intuition is to simply add both integrals:

$$A(x) = \int_0^xL(x)+R(x)dx$$

But that cannot be right because if for example you pick $x = 5$, $L(x)$ will be contributing some amount you don't want since the line goes on, etc.

I am now considering that $A(x)$ must also be piecewise, something like:

- When $x \leq 2$, $A(x) = \int_0^x L(x)dt$
- When $x>2$, $A(x) = L(2) + \int_2^x R(x)dt$

It seems like this is technically correct, but I feel like I am missing the point of the question (e.g. $A(x)$ didn't have to be piecewise like that).

Was there a more appropriate approach to this question?

Comment: I don't think you'll get A(x) to not be piecewise

Comment: if you want another way to write it, you can use the heaviside step function and write it as $x^2(1-H(x-2))+H(x-2)(4+6(x-2)-\frac{x^2-4}{2})$